# Change an image when item checked in the list. Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am using array adapter with list view. When I click on an item from the list, I can change the background drawable, but I also want to change an image(from the adapter layout) of the checked item. How can I change this image?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does that image comes from the data that is displayed? (For instance, your data has some field with a drawable?)

If so, you can change that drawable and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

(I'm assuming you are confortable with android API... if you are not I can give you a  more detailed approach)

**UPDATE**

I've never done this but try to do something similar to this:

`oldDrawable.mutate().setBackgroundDrawable(newDrawable);`

Also, reading this should help you further:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/drawable-mutations.html

Comment: No. There is an icon in my list item layout. And I want to change the drawable of that icon. I tried doing the change in onListItemClick with adaper.notifyDataSetChanged() but it does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the info.The mutate did not work in onListItemClick. Maybe I need to use the mutated drawable somewhere else when an item is selected.